# Cron job write to a new file every time it runs

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job on Python3 that runs once every hour, and writes to a new log file each time. My code is currently:

```
0 * * * * /home/user/Projects/example.py > /home/user/Projects/cron_logs/'`date +\%d\%m\%y_\%H\%M\%S`'.log 2>&1
```

There were other questions asked here that I used to put together that line, but it isn't working. It creates a file titled `date +\%d\%m\%y...`, and I can't even open the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tested this line *outside of cron* first?

Comment: It seems to me that your date is not resolving. Are you able to open the file when you surround the file name with double quotes?

Comment: Your problem is that you used single quote around your date command. In Bourne shell a single quote means to *not* interpret anything inside. So your back-tick is just a back-tick instead of running the date command.

Answer (score 2):

your `date` format is incorrect, check out `date --help` and experiment.

this also goes for actually testing the command in its entirety before installing it as a scheduled command; i.e. run `./script.py > "/target/folder/$(date).log"` command in your terminal to make sure it actually works, *then* you can put it into the crontab.

this should fix your existing entry;

```
0 * * * * /home/user/Projects/example.py > "/home/user/Projects/cron_logs/$(date +\%d\%m\%y_\%H\%M\%S).log" 2>&1
```

this would create log files with filenames looking like this : `090718_234854.log`

(I would also suggest looking at [ISO-8106](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (e.g. `date --iso-8106=s`)

Comment: `%` has to be escaped or it is interpreted by cron as initiating reading from standard input for the rest of the command.